# Load file in new window with event listener on form submission while keeping other form validations valid

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a web form that has a sales force "Web-To-Lead" form action. The end goal is to have the form submit like normal while also loading pdf into a new page.

I have two validations set up for certain form items.

The first one is a captcha validation which looks like so:

```js
var allow_submit = false

function captcha_filled () {
    allow_submit = true;
}
function captcha_expired () {
    allow_submit = false
}
function check_captcha_filled (e) {
    console.log('verify captcha')
    if (!allow_submit) {
        alert('ERROR: Please verify you are human by filling out the captcha')
        return false
    }
    captcha_expired()
    return true
}
```

(This works as expected.)

The second validation I have is for an input to be `:checked` in order for the form to submit. That code is as follows:

```js
function fnSubmit() {
    if($("input:checkbox[id='chk']").is(":checked") == false){
        alert("You must agree to collect and use your personal information.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

(This also works as expected.)

The problem comes with trying to integrate my `pdf_Download()` function while maintaining those validations. Because the form `action` is already reserved for the web-to-lead, I decided to use an `onclick` `EventListener` that generates a new window to open with the desired location. The location uses a `<?=$_REQUEST` in PHP.

Below is a minimal example of the `form` and the `js` I have attempted so far to make this work.

```html
<form action="web-to-lead" method="POST" onSubmit="return fnSubmit() & check_captcha_filled() & pdf_Download()">
<button class="def_btn bluest" name="submit">Contact</button>

<script>
function pdf_Download(e) {
    
    if($("input:checkbox[id='chk']").is(":checked") == false || !allow_submit == false) {
        e.preventDefault()
        return false
    } else {
        document.querySelectorAll('button.bluest').addEventListener("click").window.open('<?=$_REQUEST['bf_file']?>');
        return true
    }
}
</script>
```

If something is unclear please let me know.

Comment: what do you want to happen when you press the `contact` . button?

Comment: @TachibanaShin I want the form to submit like usual and for `.window.open('<?=$_REQUEST['bf_file']?>'` to open in a new window. I only want it to open into a new window if the other two validations have been validated and when the form is fully submitted.

Comment: You want to use `AND` logic in your `if` statement if you want both conditions to be met. Currently, you are using `OR` logic indicated by your `||`. Change that to `&&` so it includes both.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will work with this

> If it doesn't work please add screenshot `devtools` I will correct the answer

```php
<form action="web-to-lead" method="POST" onSubmit="fnSubmit() && check_captcha_filled() && pdf_Download()">
<button class="def_btn bluest" name="submit">Contact</button>

<script>
function pdf_Download(e) {
    
    if($("input:checkbox[id='chk']").is(":checked") == false || !allow_submit == false) {
        e.preventDefault()
        return false
    } else {
      window.open("<?=$_REQUEST['bf_file']?>");
      return true
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Kameron's comment fixed it